# Error in Integrating of Cloud computing with joomla

Tags: joomla, cloud

How can access this interface from the New Cloud Control Panel by to integrate Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

You can access this interface from the New Cloud Control Panel by clicking your username in the upper-right of the control panel and selecting "Classic Cloud Control Panel, I think this answer is useful for you